# Spring Integration. Ability to customise implementation of PublisherMetadataSource

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to configure an integration, using `@Publisher` annotation, and 
send result of the method into my messaging system.

Also, I need to send information about type of operation, that happened (**CREATED/ UPDATED/ DELETED**) in headers, I found, that this logic could be added using `org.springframework.integration.aop.PublisherMetadataSource`, that is used, during the construction of message.

I was thinking about usage of naming conventions, for example, if method, from 
which payload is returned is `created`, than add header **CREATED**, etc.

But when I've looked through the sources of construction of Aop proxy (`org.springframework.integration.aop.PublisherAnnotationAdvisor`), I understood, that I have no ability to change implementation of `PublisherMetadataSource`.

```
public PublisherAnnotationAdvisor(Class<? extends Annotation> ... publisherAnnotationTypes) {
    this.publisherAnnotationTypes = new HashSet<Class<? extends Annotation>>(Arrays.asList(publisherAnnotationTypes));
    PublisherMetadataSource metadataSource = new MethodAnnotationPublisherMetadataSource(this.publisherAnnotationTypes);
    this.interceptor = new MessagePublishingInterceptor(metadataSource);
}
```

Maybe someone could help me, how I could customise it, or add such behaviour 
to my processing pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean `@Publisher` not `@Processor`.

We should consider adding a `headers` property to `@Publisher` to allow the addition of arbitrary headers to the published message. I opened [INT-4431](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4431).

For now, you would have to override the default `PublisherAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` (under the bean name `.internalPublisherAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`) and use a custom advisor.

Comment: Gary, thanks for your reply and help ! I overridden the default one and everything works fine, I hope that this issue will be implemented, it'll be very useful and flexible functionality

Comment: [Contributions are welcome](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.adoc) :)